# Scala mastermind solver, which is the most scala-ish

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I am trying to express the classical TDD kata of mastermind in the most idiomatic scala I can. Here is a scalatest, test suite :

```
package eu.byjean.mastermind

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MastermindSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  behavior of "Mastermid"

  it should "find no good and no misplaced for a wrong guess" in {
    Mastermind.check (guess='red)(secret='blue) should equal (0,0)
  }

  it should "find all good if guess equals secret of one" in {
    Mastermind.check('blue)('blue) should equal (1,0)    
  }

  it should "find one good if guess has one good in a secret of two" in {
    Mastermind.check('blue,'red)('blue,'green) should equal (1,0)    
    Mastermind.check('green,'red)('blue,'red) should equal (1,0)
  }

  it should "find two good if guess has two good in a secret of three" in {
    Mastermind.check('blue,'red,'red)('blue,'green,'red) should equal (2,0)       
  }

  it should "find one misplaced blue in a guess of two" in {
    Mastermind.check('blue,'red)('green,'blue) should equal (0,1)
  }

  it should "find two misplaced in a guess of four" in {
    Mastermind.check('blue,'blue,'red,'red)('green,'yellow,'blue,'blue) should equal (0,2)
  }
  it should "find two misplaced colors in a guess of four" in {
    Mastermind.check('green,'blue,'yellow,'red)('green,'yellow,'blue,'blue) should equal (1,2)
  }
}
```

and my current implementation

```
package eu.byjean.mastermind

object Mastermind {
  def check(guess: Symbol*)(secret: Symbol*): (Int, Int) = {
    val (goodPairs, badPairs) = guess.zip(secret).partition { case (x, y) => x == y }
    val(guessMiss,secMiss)=badPairs.unzip
    val misplaced=guessMiss.sortBy(_.toString).zip(secMiss.sortBy(_.toString())).filter{case (x,y)=>x==y}    
    (goodPairs.size, misplaced.size)    
  }
```

In the imperative form, some people employ a map and count for each color the number of occurences of the color in the secret and in the guess (only as far as misplaced go of course). 
I tried an approach using foldLeft on the badPairs list of tuple, which lead me to variable naming problems and calling map.updated twice in the foldLeft closure which didnt seem right

Any thoughts on how to improve on the above code. It doesn't feel perfect. how would you improve it along the following axis:

- bugs: have I missed something obvious ?
- performance : this version with zip, unzip, sort, zip again most likely isn't the fastest
- readability : how would I define an implicit ordering for Symbol so I don't have to pass _.toString ,
- idiomatic scala: is there globally a more "scala-ish" way of solving this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this zipping and unzipping looks really convoluted. I think the problem here is getting too much enamored with what you can do with a Scala collection instead of focusing on the problem at hand.

One way of decreasing `zip` cost is to do it on a `view`. This way, no intermediary collection is created -- though that depends a bit on the methods being called. At any rate, `zip` is one of these methods.

It wouldn't work on your case, however, because you then go on to `partition` and `unzip` -- I'd be wary of calling such methods on a `view`, because they may end up being more expensive, not less.

I think the map approach is better, because it avoids the O(n log n) sorting. A HashMap can be built in O(n), and looked up in constant time. This is how I'd do it:

```scala
object Mastermind {
  def check(guess: Symbol*)(secret: Symbol*): (Int, Int) = {
    val numOfGoodPairs = guess.view zip secret count { case (a, b) => a == b }
    val guessesForSymbol = guess.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    val secretsForSymbol = secret.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    val unorderedGuesses = for {
      symbol <- guessesForSymbol.keys.toSeq
      secrets <- secretsForSymbol get symbol
      guesses = guessesForSymbol(symbol)
    } yield secrets min guesses
    val numOfMisplaced = unorderedGuesses.sum - numOfGoodPairs
    (numOfGoodPairs, numOfMisplaced)
  }
}
```

The first line should be pretty fast -- it will iterate once through both guess and secret, counting each time they are equal.

Computing both maps is more expensive, but it should be cheaper than sorting. Note that `mapValues` return a *view* of the values -- it does not copy any data. This is particularly interesting because it will only compute the size of map elements for keys present in both guess and secret. It is a small optimization, but you gain it almost for free.

We avoid most of the complexity by simply subtracting the number of correct guesses from the number of unordered guesses.

Comment: hello daniel, thank you very much for your answer. however, it doesn't pass the tests. one of the problem is trivial (numOfMisplaced is > 0) the other much less : given green,blue, yellow,red guess for green, yellow, blue,blue returns 1,0 instead of 1,2 ...

Comment: it looks like the problem is in the for comprehension it returns a set, not a list and therefore multiple 1 are converted to a single 1

Comment: @Jean You are correct, the problem is the `Set`. I had tested against the examples you gave, but at the last minute I decided to get `guessesForSymbol.keys` instead of `guessesForSymbol`, so that I could avoid the `count` for `guesses`. That changed the result from `Iterable` to `Set`, causing the problem. Sorry about that...

Comment: Ok that did it  thanks. A suggestion and a question:  the first line of the for comprehension can be rewritten as (symbol,guesses) <- guessesForSymbol.elements.toSeq avoids a second call to get further down. Also I remember reading that for comprehension were logically equivalent to using one of map, flatMap or something like that. Do you know which ?

Comment: I think I got it:val unorderedGuesses = guessesForSymbol.map {
      case (symbol, guesses) => secretsForSymbol.getOrElse(symbol,0) min(guesses)
    } not sure it brings much to the table

Comment: @Jean the first line can be written as `(symbol, guesses) <- guessesForSymbol` -- no need to transform it further. That's what I had originally written, but that will compute `_.size` on all elements of `guessesForSymbol`. Since that's a list, `size` is O(n). The way I wrote it, I'll only compute `_.size` for guesses that actually match a secret.

Comment: @Jean And, yes, for comprehensions map to `flatMap`, `map` and either `withFilter` or `filter` (depending on availability) if they `yield` something, or `foreach` and `withFilter`/`filter` if they do not. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1052476/53013) for details.

Comment: regarding the form (symbol, guesses) <- guessesForSymbol, you say that it will compute _size on all elements of guessesForSymbol. Does that mean that it is not computed already on line 4.  I haven't understood scala lazy eval yet. I know it exists but not how it works.

Comment: @Jean Yes, it means `_.size` is not computed on line 4. I'll let the description on Scaladoc to speak for itself: "The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements." Technically, we call this non-strict instead of lazy. We reserve "lazy" for those instances where the value if computed only once and cached. In this case, every time you access an element of the resulting collection, `_.size` will be recomputed. If you have further doubts, ask on Stack Overflow, please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments they were very helpful. I'll read up on non strict and lazy, ask my questions later.

Answer (score 0):

This has *worse* performance, but I hope it's a little bit more readable:

```
def check(guess: Symbol*)(secret: Symbol*): (Int, Int) = {
  def goodBad(f: Seq[Symbol] => Seq[Symbol], s1: Seq[Symbol], s2:Seq[Symbol]) = 
    f(s1) zip f(s2) partition {case (x, y) => x == y }
  val (goodPairs, badPairs) = goodBad(identity, guess, secret)
  val (guessMiss, secMiss) = badPairs unzip
  val misplaced = goodBad(_.sortBy(_.toString), guessMiss, secMiss)._1
  (goodPairs.size, misplaced.size)    
}
```

The main problem is that Scala's `Tuple2` is just too dumb: You can't do much with it except pattern matching, there is no `map` or `copy` method etc.

The `String`-based sorting isn't nice, but I don't know a better way.

I wouldn't sweat too much about performance. Often you have to make a choice between fast and pretty, and in this context I would choose "pretty".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not exactly what I was expecting :)